# SAM Deployment failed Error- Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state

Tags: aws-cloudformation, sam

When I try to deploy package on SAM, the very first status comes in cloud formation console is ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS after that it gets changed to ROLLBACK_COMPLETE

I have tried deleting the stack and trying again, but every time same issue occurs. 
Error in terminal looks like this-

```
Sourcing local options from ./SAMToolkit.devenv
SAM_PARAM_PKG environment variable not set
SAMToolkit will operate in legacy mode.
Please set SAM_PARAM_PKG in your .devenv file to run modern packaging.
Run 'sam help package' for more information
Runtime: java
Attempting to assume role from AWS Identity Broker using account 634668058279
Assumed role from AWS Identity Broker successfully.
Deploying stack sam-dev* from template: /home/***/1.0/runtime/sam/template.yml
sam-additional-artifacts-url.txt was not found, which is fine if there is no additional artifacts uploaded
Replacing BATS::SAM placeholders in template...
Uploading template build/private/tmp/sam-toolkit.yml to s3://***/sam-toolkit.yml
make_bucket failed: s3://sam-dev* An error occurred (BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.
upload: build/private/tmp/sam-toolkit.yml to s3://sam-dev*/sam-toolkit.yml

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id sam-dev* does not exist
sam-dev* will be created.
Creating ChangeSet ChangeSet-2020-01-20T12-25-56Z
Deploying stack sam-dev*. Follow in console: https://aws-identity-broker.amazon.com/federation/634668058279/CloudFormation
ChangeSet ChangeSet-2020-01-20T12-25-56Z in sam-dev* succeeded
            "StackStatus": "REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS",
sam-dev* reached REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS
Deploying stack sam-dev*. Follow in console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-west-2
Waiting for stack-create-complete

Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state

Command failed.
Please see the logs above.
```

Comment: Can you share the template you're using that generates this error?

Answer (score 7):

I set SQS as event source for Lambda, but didn't provided the permissions like this

```
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
      - sqs:ReceiveMessage
      - sqs:DeleteMessage
      - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
      Resource: "*"
```

in lambda policies.

I found this error in "Events" tab of "CloudFormation" service.